# Windows Sandbox did not install

Tags: windows-10, sandbox

I enabled Windows Sandbox:

[image]

and restarted my machine.

But there is no Windows Sandbox in Start Menu:

[image]

And there is no `%windir%\system32\WindowsSandbox.exe` file on my machine

```
C:\>dir %windir%\system32\WindowsSandbox.exe                                                                                                                                                                                        
Volume in drive C has no label.                                                                                                                                                                                    
Volume Serial Number is 0C2C-0782                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Directory of C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
File Not Found
```

Comment: Just to confirm it's enable, run the following PowerShell command as an Administrator, `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName "Containers-DisposableClientVM" -All -Online`.  You should also verify that hardware virtualization is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to enabling Sandbox (a special purpose limited container) you also need to enable Windows HyperVisor Platform and also Virtual Machine platform.

Restart after doing this.

That plus Sandbox will allow Sandbox to run. I have it running here.